# Why my table filter is removing the table headers?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, bootstrap-4, frontend

I'm trying to implement this table filter which i found at this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_filters.asp) but for some reason my filter is removing my table headers and in the examples it doesn't remove the headers, I wonder what I'm doing wrong here?

This is my table:

```
    <input type="text" id="inputFilter" placeholder="Procurar agendamentos..">

<table class="table table-hover table-dark" id="tableAgendamentos">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Data</th>
            <th scope="col">Animal</th>
            <th scope="col">Procedimento</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Valor</th>
            <th scope="col">Nota Fiscal</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (Agendamento agendamento in Model.ListaAgendamentos)
        {
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">@agendamento.DataHoraInicio</th>
                <td>@agendamento.nomeAnimal</td>
                <td>@agendamento.NomeServico</td>                
                @if(agendamento.prioridadeAgendamento == 3)
                {
                    <td class="text-success">Em até 7 dias</td>
                }else if(agendamento.prioridadeAgendamento == 2)
                {
                    <td class="text-primary">Em até 30 dias</td>
                }else
                {
                    <td class="text-danger">Atrasado/Vencido</td>
                }
                <td>R$100,00</td>
                <td><a href="url">Baixar</a></td>
            </tr>
        }            
        </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my script:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#inputFilter").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $("#tableAgendamentos tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

[This is how my table looks without searching anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nifL.png)

[This is how my table looks after searching for some data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YP5P.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the header is getting filtered out.
I think you could give it a try with an id for tbody instead of the whole table id in the script.

Looking at the tutorial, there seems to be a point at the end stating

> Note that we start the search in tbody, to prevent filtering the table headers.

Comment: Wow thanks! I just changed the id from the table tag to the tbody tag and now it works perfectly! I will update this as the answer as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 0):

I think error is about this

```
$("#tableAgendamentos tr")
```

I think give a class name to tr instead of above code then try again